# Can I use a Spanish word in my software license?

Tags: licensing, language

> This License is a **libre** and copyleft license for software, specifically designed ...

Can I use the Spanish world "libre" in the preamble and following legal document? "Libre" means *"the state of being free", as in "liberty", not monetary value* to emphasize the nature of the license?

I also want to use it multiple times in the document.

Comment: "Free" also means "the state of being free."  You can be free to copy my work, and I can make it available to you free of charge.  There's no need to go complicating things by adopting words whose pronunciation is unclear.  (Does it rhyme with fibre?  Is it in fact from Spanish or instead from French, and should English speakers pronounce it accordingly?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A copyleft license grants access as long as the licensee abides by the terms, which practically makes them contracts, and mixing languages in contracts are valid as long as [the parties understand them](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83773/is-a-contract-written-in-a-mix-of-languages-valid%5D). That's why licenses usually lay down the specific meaning of the terms they'll be using, to avoid [false friends](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209789/is-there-a-term-for-a-foreign-word-that-looks-like-an-english-word-but-has-a-com) interpretation latter.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to borrow a word from another language, or for that matter use any word that isn't widely accepted as an English word, or even use an English word that might be at risk of being misinterpreted, all you have to do is define the word explicitly.  Better still, hire a lawyer to do it, because you might overlook something that you didn't even know should be taken into account.